# Python multiprocessing through filenames

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I just wrote a code that basically writes the filenames to .csv file.

But unfortunately can't make it run multiprocess.

Anyone can help?

```
def fn(src):
    with open(xlsx_file, "a", newline="", encoding="UTF8") as f:
        resultwriter = csv.writer(f)
        for root, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(src):
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith(".xml") or filename.endswith(".dcm"):
                    if not "1.2." in filename:
                        resultwriter.writerow([filename, os.path.join(root, filename)])
                        print(f"{filename}"
                              f"{root}")



fn(src)
```

Comment: "xlsx" is not "csv". Although this is just the variable name you are using, it is an important distinction to be learned.

Comment: Now, concerning your question per se - what is there to "multiprocess"? You gahter the paths for all files of itnerest, in a CSV file, ok. If you want to further process each of these files, please come with a minimum reproducible example indicating the action to perform in each file that should be done in parallel: you won't gain any considerable speed by making the file discovery and name gathering multi-processed at all.

Comment: @jsbueno sorry my bad, it's .csv on original code.

Comment: @jsbueno I was trying to say how to gather those files in parallel? I have 9 million files to check and at least 10% of those files needs to be written